# How to feed same result from tf.train.shuffle_batch to different functions?

Tags: tensorflow

Following code is in the context of Generative Adversarial Networks.

`input_pipeline` is the standard input pipeline you would expect from CIFAR10. The key thing to note is that it returns a batch from `tf.train.shuffle_batch()`. I'm doing this in my code:

```py
images = input_pipeline(filename_queue)
gen_images = generator(images)
discriminator_logits = discriminator(images, gen_images)
```

However, since `images` is a placeholder that draws from the queue, calling `images` twice like that would result in a totally different set of images. Specifically, generator would receive Set A of images and discriminator would receive Set B of images. I want the discriminator to receive Set A as well.

What's the best way to solve this?

Comment: Use it as input to var.assign, then feed var to your functions

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov - could you promote to answer?

Comment: P.S. I realized my question may not be correct. It doesn't work this way. I'll check and edit it.